# Getting camera and geolocation permission ahead of time

Tags: javascript, html, permissions, camera, geolocation

I'm building a web-app that uses the device's camera and location services. The browser (I'm sticking to Chrome for now) asks the user for permission to do so on the page where the service is used.

I want the interface to be able to ask for permission at an early stage in the workflow so the pop-up dialogs don't come up during the use of the app. I know they would go away after the first visit to a page, but I want to avoid it the first time too.

Javascript is pretty much the only tool I know how to use, and I know each page has a separate Javascript execution context, so I can't get references to the objects on one page and hand them over to another.

So *is* there a way that will work? Maybe I need to learn some other technology?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in the browser, then I would suggest creating a sort of initialization page before going to the actual app page.

In the ini page you can call all permissions and download+cache all needed app scripts and also validate which permissions were accepted and not. Kinda something like when using GMail you go through their ini page first before getting to the actual GMail ui.

Once the ini page has completely loaded simply redirect to the actual app.

---

If you want to do it outside the browser and still use the same web technologies, take a look at [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) or [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/).

Both tools above lets you build cross platform desktop apps with web technologies. Things like asking for `camera` and `geolocation` can be done without user permission (as I recall. not sure)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem isn't getting my code to remember the permissions, it's getting the browser to remember permissions from page to page. The browser treats every page independently, so I need a workaround for that. It would be great if I could get a reference to the user media object and pass that around, and that seems like it might be possible, but I don't see how to do it.

Comment: you could just cover up the page with an overlay and do your permissions. on top of that overlay. once everything is set up just remove the overlay. It still has the ini page thing but on the same page.

Comment: That's a great idea except I need to load other pages between getting the permissions and using them. That overlay does give me an idea though. Maybe I could do permissions and usage on the main page and load other pages to the overlay. Does the overlay work that way, I wonder...